# Error in build at react-native run-android

Tags: react-native, build, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I want to run my apps in cmd with react-native run-android but i have some problem without build the apps..

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'.

  > Could not read path 'D:\Data Andrian\Tugas-Tugas\Tugas Andrian\Android\Belajar React Native\AsihPutera\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\mergeJniLibs\debug\0\lib\armeabi-v7a'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 34s

I hope i can get some solution in here .. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause is related migration to Androidx, google play service updated to androidX

If you are using `real-native-info`, please upgrade. It will solve your problem with **2.1.2**

See [here apply link](http://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25294#issuecomment-503024749)

> Note: Upgrading `com.google.android.gms` to 17.0.0 will cause many
>   problems.

It will work help for you